# column reference id is ambiguous postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a new query postgresql with alias but i still have the same problem of ambiguous column.

```sql
select a.id_application
      from  (SELECT * FROM t_mission as PM
         LEFT JOIN t_mission_raf rm on PM.id_mission= rm.id_rm
        LEFT JOIN t_mission_roles AS mr ON PM.id_mission = mr.id_mission
        LEFT JOIN t_role AS r ON r.id_role = mr.id_role
        LEFT JOIN t_appli AS app ON app.id_application = r.id_application
         WHERE PM.type_mission = 1 AND PM.id_mission =24730) as a
```

Result:

```
Error msg : SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "id_application" is ambiguous
  Position : 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `SELECT *` but exlipcitly select the columns you need. Make sure to only select `app.id_application` *or* `r.id_application`. Or use `as` for one of those.